# How fill one row in listbox with array? (more than 10 columns)

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, listbox

I have a `ListBox1` in `UserForm1`. When I send a multi-row array to a `.List`, everything works. But when I send only a one-row array, the values in the `ListBox1` are arranged one below the other in first column. Independent of use Application.Transpose.

I tried to write a condition and a for loop, but it doesn't work.
Run-time error 381
Could not set the List property. Invalid property array index.
`.AddItem` cannot be used because there are more than 10 columns

Do you have any other solution?

```
Dim sumItem As Integer: sumItem = 0 'later between 1 and 5000
.
.
ReDim Preserve arrSort(0 To (columnCount - 1 + 2), 0 To sumItem - 1)
.
.
Call Load(UserForm1) 'to be able to manipulate components
If sumItem = 1 Then 'if only one ROW is loaded in the array
Dim qq As Byte
For qq = 0 To (columnCount - 1)
UserForm1.ListBox1.List(0, qq) = arrSort(qq, 0) 'need to fill the LISTBOX ROW here
Next qq
ElseIf sumItem > 1 Then
UserForm1.ListBox1.List = Application.Transpose(arrSort) 'if more than one ROW is filled, this works
Else
End If
UserForm1.Show
```

---

Thank's to @Tim Williams
This work for me:

```
Dim sumItem As Integer: sumItem = 0 'later between 1 and 5000
.
.
ReDim Preserve arrSort(0 To (columnCount - 1 + 2), 0 To sumItem - 1) 'the dimensions are reversed
.
.
Call Load(UserForm1) 'to be able to manipulate components
If sumItem = 1 Then 'if only one ROW is loaded in the array
Dim qq As Byte
Dim arrTmp(0 To 0, 0 To (columnCount - 1)) As Variant 'auxiliary array for dimension exchange
For qq = 0 To (columnCount - 1)
arrTmp(0, qq) = arrSort(qq, 0)
Next qq
UserForm1.ListBox1.List = arrSort
ElseIf sumItem > 1 Then
UserForm1.ListBox1.List = Application.Transpose(arrSort) 'if more than one ROW is filled, this works
Else
End If
UserForm1.Show
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```vb
Const NUM_COLS As Long = 20

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Dim lstInit(0 To 0, 0 To NUM_COLS - 1), r As Long, c As Long
    
    Me.ListBox1.ColumnCount = NUM_COLS
    'fill a row of dummy data....
    For c = 0 To NUM_COLS - 1
        lstInit(0, c) = "R1:C" & (c + 1)
    Next c
    Me.ListBox1.List = lstInit
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim arr, c As Long, ub As Long
    arr = AddARow(Me.ListBox1.List) 'get the existing listbox data and add a row
    ub = UBound(arr, 1)
    For c = 0 To UBound(arr, 2)
        arr(ub, c) = "R" & (ub + 1) & ":C" & (c + 1) 'populate the added row
    Next c
    Me.ListBox1.List = arr 'refresh the listbox
End Sub

'add one "row" to a 2D array and return the new array
Function AddARow(lst)
    Dim lstNew, r As Long, c As Long
    ReDim lstNew(0 To UBound(lst, 1) + 1, 0 To UBound(lst, 2))
    'copy existing data
    For r = 0 To UBound(lst, 1)
        For c = 0 To UBound(lst, 2)
            lstNew(r, c) = lst(r, c)
        Next c
    Next r
    AddARow = lstNew
End Function
```

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe my description was not clear. I don't need to add row to existing data. I need to add a "row" to an empty `ListBox1`. The problem is that an array with "one row" display as a column in the `Listbox1`.

Comment: There's no problem setting the `List` property to (eg) an array dimensioned as (0 to 0, 0 to 9)

Comment: Updated my answer to only add a single row in `UserForm_Activate`

Comment: My array have interchanged dimensions (0 To 9, 0 To 0). So the easiest way will be to create a new array in the for loop, where will I exchange the dimensions?

Comment: Why not use an array of the correct dimensions?  There's no need to "flip" it just so it can be resized...

Comment: Earlier in the code I use ReDim Preserve several times and it allows you to change ONLY the last dimension. Or is it possible? I'm not very advanced in VBA ...

Comment: You can only resize the last dimension of a multi-dimension array, but you can copy the contents to a larger array instead (as I did in `AddARow`)

Comment: @TimWilliams Though array I prefer array assignments to a listbox, it may be of some interest that after a starting initializing by a 2-dim (even empty) array, any eventual `.AddItem` | `.RemoveItem` action isn't restricted to the 10-columns limitation (at least under MS 365). So you could code the `AddARow` procedure also via `.AddItem` :-)

Comment: @T.M. - I'm not a big listbox user, so this was just the first thing I tried.  Good to know there's also a different approach.